# Nokogiri Ruby Gem not working for all URLs

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm making my own web-scraper for the final project and could use a little help.

I'm using Nokogiri. The web-scraper finds all the words on a webpage and uses a dictionary to count the frequency of each word, then returns the top ten words on the website. I can pass in as many website as I want and it will still work. So I can pass it `http://fox.com`, `http/cnbc.com`, etc. The program works well with these sites, but for some sites I get an error. For example, `http://facebook` doesn't work and it says redirection forbidden.

Here is my code so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class Scraper

  attr_accessor :url, :words, :arguments

  def initialize(*args)
    @words = Hash.new("No Match Found")
    @arguments = args
    compiler
    print_results
  end

  def mechansim(site)
    boring_words = ["the","to", "in","if","of","all","and","the","for","news","is","on","a","this","with","at","continue","more","be","from","could","as","by","he","she","who","what","not",
      "newswidget","newswidgetfooter","pm"]
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site))
    page.search('script').each {|el| el.unlink}
    links = page.css('body').inner_text.downcase.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '').split(' ')
    links.each do |x|
      if @words.has_key?(x) === true && boring_words.include?(x) === false
        @words[x] += 1
      else 
        @words[x] =1
      end
    end
    if @arguments[0].length > 0
      compiler
    end
  end

  def compiler
    @arguments.each do |argument| 
      argument = argument[0]
      site = argument
      arguments[0].shift
      mechansim(site)
    end
  end


  def print_results
    puts "------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @words = @words.sort_by {|k, v| v}.reverse.to_h 
    print @words.take(20)
    puts "------------------------------------------------------------------"
  end

end

Scraper.new(["http://foxnews.com"])
```

Comment: Some sites don't like being scraped. Funny about that :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Nokogiri as it doesn't retrieve the content from the site, it only parses what is passed to it. You're using OpenURI to read a site, and passing it an incomplete URL. Facebook isn't `http://facebook`, it's `http://facebook.com`. You could write code to complete the URL if it's missing the TLD, but that's often inaccurate or misleading and your code can end up being redirected somewhere you don't want. OpenURI follows redirects IF it's given a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTPS version of the facebook url: `https://facebook.com`.

Comment: HTTP isn't `https`. Please clarify what you're saying. The problem isn't due to https vs http, it's because the OP is missing the TLD.

Comment: If you run the code you will see that open-uri fails to process 302 returned from `http://facebook.com`. The solution is to use the redirection target.